# How to enforce atomatic render for xterm.js

Tags: reactjs, xtermjs

I am using xterm.js with React. Is there a way I can replace current Terminal.buffer with new buffer. Currently my code look likes this.

```js
term.clear()
newBuffer.map(line => term.writeln(line))
term.scrollToBottom()
```

However, after the `term.clear()` is called, the terminal buffler cleared, **and** **the terminal renders.**  Then I write new data into the buffer, the terminal renders again. The terminal renders twice to replace the current buffer. I want the terminal simply renders once. In another word, when I called the term.clear(), the terminal do not rerender. I cannot find the API for this behavior, can somebody be so kind to help?

In another word, I want a `clear` method without firing the `scroll` event
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yxo8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the kind response here, the atomatic render is disabled by design. To solve the above question, the correct code looks like this:

```js
domRef.current.style.visibility = 'hidden'
term.clear()
newBuffer.map(line => term.writeln(line))
term.scrollToBottom()
domRef.current.style.visibility = 'show'
```

https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/3859#event-6795418246